# Reuse TFloatAnimation Delphi XE5

Tags: android, delphi, animation

Put a FloatAnimation a button and the application panel, the button onClick put the FloatAnimation1.enabled: = true; and the animation runs normally, but if I click on the button again the animation does not run again. Ie I need the component FloatAnimation run whenever I click the button and not just the first time.

Comment: `FloatAnimation1.Enabled := False; FloatAnimation1.Enabled := True;` ? Or `FloatAnimation1.Stop; FloatAnimation1.Start;` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I read the documentations, it would be easier for you to use the `Start` method.

```
FloatAnimation1.Start;
```

This will restart the animation. Setting `Enabled` to `True` will call `Start`, but only if `Enabled` is currently `False`. So it's easiest just to call the `Start` method directly.